# How to check file content is missing in File Upload Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API to upload a single file which is sent along the request body. I have the below code to read file binaries from the stream

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = t.Result)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        stream.CopyTo(ms);
                        byte[] fileBinaries = ms.ToArray();
                        //logic to process the file
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception handling logic
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        });
        return task;
```

The API works fine when called with file being uploaded; and returns Http status code **201**. But if I didn't attached file to the API call still it returns the same code as there is no check on binary data received. I want  to add that check to return appropriate error message to user.

I tried to perform this check by evaluating the length of fileBinaries byte array read from Request.Content. But the array has few bytes in it which represents text **[object FileList]** (don't know how this bytes are filled in the array as i haven't attached any file with the API call). So this won't work for me.

I also tried using the **HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count** but it always returns 0 (Probably due to the file binaries sent in request body) so not suitable for my check.

I can't rely on any headers like **File Name** as those are not sent in request.

Any help how to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using MultipartMemoryStreamProvider which is ideal for file uploads using webapi

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
{

    var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

    foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
    {
        var fileBytes = await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Here fileBytes may not have those 17 bytes.

Comment: Can I use the same Task based pattern and just replace .ReadasStreamAsync() with .ReadAsMultipartAsync()? As I am getting error cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier  with async-await construct.

Comment: Getting error: Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content-type header value. 'HttpContent' instances must have a content-type header starting with 'multipart/'.\r\nParameter name: content"